# Not able to make element stick to the bottom when offscreen in IE 11, just like in css sticky

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to replicate the same behavior as in this
[codepen](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/MZZVjw) in IE 11 (does not have css sticky)

I am able to detect when the item is offscreen at the start with:

```
if (
  $(".main-content").height() + $(".main-content").offset().top <
  $(".main-footer").offset().top
)
```

but then after it reaches the end of the scroll (in this case the page), I did not manage to check when it goes offscreen again. It is probably something simple as subtracting the scroll to figure out if the element is offscreen, I am just stuck...

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/deleite/pen/GRqNVrR) where I stuck am now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IE doesn't support `<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#Browser_compatibility) so you can't use this tag in IE 11. You can monitor the scroll bar changes through JavaScript, and then change its class according to the position of the element.

Here is the code you can refer to:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scroH = $(document).scrollTop();
  var viewH = $(window).height();
  var contentH = $(document).height();

  $('.main-footer').addClass('main-footer1')

  if (scroH > 100) {}
  if (contentH - (scroH + viewH) <= 100) { // The height from the bottom is less than 100px
  }
  if (contentH <= (scroH + viewH + 100)) {
    $('.main-footer').removeClass('main-footer1')
    $('.main-footer').addClass('main-footer2')
  } else {
    $('.main-footer').addClass('main-footer1')
    $('.main-footer').removeClass('main-footer2')
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.main-container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 10px green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.main-container * {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: dashed 5px #000;
}

.main-container *+* {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #aaa;
}

.main-content {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

.main-footer {
  border-color: red;
}

.main-footer1 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 570px;
}

.main-footer2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-content">MAIN contentH</div>
  <footer class="main-footer">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Result in IE 11:
[image]